# Where are the three run time errors?

Tags: java, time

This is the code, where are the run time errors? I tried and tried to find it but I just could not, does anyone else see where these errors could be within the code?

```
public class HasErrors
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner("System.in");
        x = in.readInt();
        System.out.print("Please enter another integer: ");
        x = in.readInt();
        System.out.println("The sum is " + x + y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: How do you know there are errors if you're not receiving any?

Comment: `"System.in"` can’t be parsed as an integer.

Comment: `x = in.readInt();` twice, and no `y = in.readInt();` probably isn't an error, but probably not what's intended.

Comment: I don't know about runtime errors, but you have a subtle logic error in there...examine carefully which variables you are using and when. I don't think you will get the results you're expecting with the code as it is now.

Comment: `Scanner` doesn't have `readInt()` — try `nextInt()`

Comment: When you have a question about runtime (or any other type of) errors, you should post the error message it's giving you, as well as the input you're using, the output it's giving you, and how that differs from what you expect.

Comment: Additionally, code that doesn’t compile can’t possibly have any runtime errors.

Comment: @David This is a "find-the-errors" homework assignment that OP hasn't even tried to run through the compiler.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am in a starter CS class for college and I'm lost! I just thought that this may have helped, however I am still just as confused.

Comment: @KatieKrueger Start by trying to compile the code, and the compiler will identify some issues for you. If you use an IDE (I prefer Eclipse), it will tell you as you go if there are problems with the code. Finally, documentation for all of the standard Java library (including `Scanner`) is available at http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/.

Answer (score 1):

If you're instantiating a new `Scanner` with `System.in` it shouldn't have quotes around it:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Comment: Maybe OP wanted to use a `Scanner` to scan a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Well if a user enters in somethign other than a number, say `Hello World`, then `readInt()` will throw an `InputMismatchException`. Also the `Scanner` class does not have a `readInt` function. I think you meant to put `nextInt`.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the readInt errors already mentioned, X and Y will be concatenated in the println statement rather than added.  This could be fixed by putting the x + y in parentheses.